# Obter endereço IP LUA

Tags: lua

Quero obter o endereço IP atraves do codigo LUA. Tenho um exemplo de codigo que funcione mas obtenho o IP da interface LAN.

```
local hote, _ = socket.dns.toip(socket.dns.gethostname())
```

Como posso obter o IP de outra interface wifi? é possivel escolher a interface?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se a biblioteca `socket` permite isso.

Uma alternativa é ler o relatório de `ifconfig` com `io.popen("ifconfig"):read"*a"`.

Se você sabe o nome da interface, então pode usar esse nome na chamada de `ifconfig`.

Infelizmente, o formato do relatório de `ifconfig` parece depender da plataforma: são diferentes em Linux e Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

IFCONFIG NO LINUX

Caso queira saber usar o IP pelo ifconfig basta fazer isto no bloco de nota:

```
print (io.popen ("LANG=C /sbin/ifconfig eth0"):lines ()())



print (io.popen ("LANG=C /sbin/ifconfig wlan0"):lines ()())
```

Depois que salvou com o nome "MOSTRA_MEU_IP.txt", digite isto:

```
 ┌─[root@parrot] #lua MOSTRA_MEU_IP.txt                                    
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:22:64:e0:d4:d4

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 78:44:76:9a:a0:47  

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
```

DIR ou LS

```
print (io.popen ("LANG=C /bin/ls"):lines ()())
```